How to use an identifier other than "email" for users in Firebase Authentication + OIDC
I've set up Firebase Authentication for my app with an OIDC provider. In this OIDC provider, the email address isn't required to be unique. For instance, users from the same company could share their company's email address.
When I log in to the app through Firebase Authentication however, Firebase uses the email as the "identifier". This means that a different user with the same email ends up sharing the same Firebase Authentication user.
Is it possible to tell Firebase Authentication to use something else as the identifier (eg. the "sub")?
Alternatively, could there be any additional setup I need to do in our OIDC provider the signal to Firebase what it should use as an identifier? The provider uses ASP.NET Identity + OpenIDDict.
Thanks.

Firebase has a configuration option that determines whether email addresses have to be unique in a project. It's on by default, but if you turn it off you can have multiple users with the same email address.

Are you referring to the "User account linking" settings? As far as I understand, that affects users from different providers only? I'm using a single provider where emails are not unique.

The setting changed names a few times over the years, but it used to apply to accounts in the default email/password provider too - so you might want to give it a try.
